# Find closest class and slideDown in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I'm looking to add a "View More" button to my page. In that view button is another ul, which currently has the class of "hidden-list"

When the user clicks "View More" I would like it to slideToggle the hidden-list element.

I'm trying with closest, but not having any luck.

My current jQuery is :

```
$('li.list-group-item a.view-more').click(function()
{
    $(this).closest('.list-group-item').closest('ul').slideDown();
})
```

Check out my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vkqd2y21/) for HTML markup etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('li.list-group-item a.view-more').click(function()
{
    $(this).closest('.list-group').find('.hidden-list').slideDown();
})
```

Comment: Excellent! Many thanks for speedy answer too *thumbs up*